# How to fit a longtext data type in a HTML table

Tags: php, html

This is my code:

```
<table width="90%" border="10" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td>
<pre>
        <?php echo"$notes_1";?>
</pre>
</td></tr></table>
```

`$notes_1` is a longtext data type retrieved from MySQL database. It has some really long sentences without line breaks. When i am calling this variable inside above table i am getting a very long horizontal scroll in the browser. I want the whole formatted text to be inside the table of width 90% of browser. Please tell me how is it possible?

Comment: For starters do not use `pre` tags

Comment: You can also style your pre with a max-width and set overflow:scroll